# Rails Simple_form f.association, Chosen Multiple Select

Tags: select, associations, simple-form

The default for the empty unselected chosen multiple select is:

"Select Some Options"

How do you change this on a per-field basis?  That is not by changing the default in the JavaScript or even at the selector level?

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy to fix, but I looked all over and didn't find anything but far more complicated answers and bad/inflexible answers.

The simplest most effective answer I found was to simply add:

```
<%= f.association :law_guardians, input_html: {'data-placeholder' => 'Select L Guardian'}, label: 'L Guardians', :label_method => lambda { |lg| "#{lg.cl_name}, #{lg.cf_name}" } %>
```